# How to identify a job given from your user account and kill it

Tags: linux, unix, kill

I had given a job in a remote server yesterday from my home. The command was

```
sh run.sh >& out &
```

The run.sh will excute a program (average.f) more than 1000 times recurssively. 
Today, in my office, I found some mistake in my run.sh. So I would like to kill it.

I used top command, but it is not showing the run.sh. It is only showing average.f. So, once, I killed it with kill PID, it is again starting average.f with another PID and producing outputs.

ps -u is not showing either run.sh or average.f.

Can anybody please help me how to kill this job.

Comment: Could average.f have started a *new* average.f "recursively" *before* the kill signal was sent?

Comment: Perhaps this question should better be asked on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BTW, showing the code in `run.sh` could help.

Comment: Thanks to @BasileStarynkevitch and all for trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find your job id with the process or application name . example is given below - I am killing java process here

### ps -aef|grep java

// the above command will give you pid, now fire below command to kill that job

### kill -9 pid

// here pid is a number which you get from the first command

Comment: No, use `kill -TERM` then `killl -QUIT`

Comment: Thank you @Manoj. This works fine. I was trying for 2 hrs to stop this job. Now you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep run.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` but first `kill -TERM` then `kill -QUIT` then if that fails `kill -KILL`

Comment: Now I could identify the job and its PID with ps -ef | grep run.sh. But when I am using kill PID, it is showing 'there is no such process'.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pstree(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) (probably as `pstree -p`) to list the process tree hierarchy, then [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) (first with `-TERM`, then with `-QUIT`, and if that does not work, at last with `-KILL`) your topmost shell process running `run.sh` (or else the few "higher" processes). Perhaps use [killall(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html) or [pidof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pidof.1.html) (or [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) or `pkill`)

<sup>You might want to kill the [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group), with a negative pid.</sup>

You should **never at first `kill -KILL` a process** (but only at *last* resort); some programs (e.g. database servers, sophisticated numerical computations with [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), ...) have installed a `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT` signal handler to clean up their mess and e.g. save some state (on the disk) in a sane way. If you `kill -KILL` them, they could leave the mess uncleaned (since `SIGKILL` cannot be caught, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)....)

BTW, you should use `ps auxw` to list all processes, read [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

Comment: He could use alternatively `ps -fp $(pgrep -u kayan sh)` if he is on some kind of MAC or similar, they do not have pstree. Hope they have pgrep and pkill.

Comment: The OP has tagged his question Linux. He is not on MacOSX and certainly can install `pstree`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. I don't know who had downvoted your answer. But I sincerely thank and appreciate your time in trying to solve my problem.

Comment: The important lesson is to **avoid using `kill -KILL`** (or `kill -9`) **at first**. It is a very bad habit, and it could bite you hard.... (e.g. with bad luck, `kill -KILL $(pidof mysqld)` could lose all the data in your mysql databases)